# Select the previous business day by using SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, date

What is the purely MySQL way of getting yesterday, but only for business days?

Right now I'm using `SUBDATE(CURRENT_DATE, 1))` for yesterday but on Monday it's returning Sunday.

I would like it to return results for the previous Friday's date, or in other words, the previous business day.

I should have clarified I'm trying to use this in the `WHERE` part of the query (and also the subquery).

```
SELECT ... WHERE DATE(timestamp) = SUBDATE(CURRENT_DATE, 1))
```

Here is the whole query:

```
SELECT r.drivername, l.branchcity as location, COUNT(o.ordernum) as deliveries, COUNT(x.pictures) as pics, CONCAT(ROUND((COUNT(x.pictures) / COUNT(o.ordernum))*100,2),'%') as percentage_having_images 
FROM deliveries d, drivers r, locations l, staging s, stations t, orders o LEFT OUTER JOIN 
(SELECT a.ordernum AS pictures
FROM orders a WHERE a.stationID = '16' AND DATE(a.scantime) = SUBDATE(CURRENT_DATE, 1)) x 
ON x.pictures = o.ordernum
WHERE o.deliveryID = d.ID AND d.driverID = r.ID AND s.locationID = l.ID AND o.stationID = t.ID AND o.stagingID = s.ID AND t.ID IN ('11','12','13') AND DATE(o.scantime) = SUBDATE(CURRENT_DATE, 1) GROUP BY s.locationID, r.drivername ORDER BY s.locationID, percentage_having_images DESC
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
SELECT ..
.
.
AND DATE(a.scantime) = (CASE WEEKDAY(CURRENT_DATE) 
                             WHEN 0 THEN SUBDATE(CURRENT_DATE,3)
                             WHEN 6 THEN SUBDATE(CURRENT_DATE,2) 
                             WHEN 5 THEN SUBDATE(CURRENT_DATE,1)
                             ELSE SUBDATE(CURRENT_DATE,1) 
                        END)
..
..
```

Comment: To make it slightly more efficient, you can ditch the `WHEN 5` part, as it's the same to the `ELSE` part.

Comment: A similar method works for "Next Business Day" in MySQL also:  
(CASE WEEKDAY(CURRENT_DATE)
 WHEN 6 THEN ADDDATE(CURRENT_DATE,1)
 WHEN 5 THEN ADDDATE(CURRENT_DATE,2)
 WHEN 4 THEN ADDDATE(CURRENT_DATE,3)
 ELSE ADDDATE(CURRENT_DATE,1)
 END)

Answer (score 0):

try this to get the day:

```
     SELECT
CASE DAYOFWEEK(SUBDATE(CURRENT_DATE, 1))
      WHEN 1 THEN SELECT SUBDATE(CURRENT_DATE, 3);
      WHEN 7 THEN SELECT SUBDATE(CURRENT_DATE, 2);
      ELSE
        BEGIN
          SUBDATE(CURRENT_DATE, 1);
        END;
    END CASE;
```

THEN use a subquery

```
SELECT ... WHERE DATE(timestamp) = (SELECT
    CASE DAYOFWEEK(SUBDATE(CURRENT_DATE, 1))
          WHEN 1 THEN SELECT SUBDATE(CURRENT_DATE, 3);
          WHEN 7 THEN SELECT SUBDATE(CURRENT_DATE, 2);
          ELSE
            BEGIN
              SUBDATE(CURRENT_DATE, 1);
            END;
        END CASE);
```

Comment: This is not working for me, perhaps because this is a subquery of a subquery, I'm already in a subquery for one of the comparisons to yesterday, and in the top level query for another one.

Comment: Maybe adding the query to a function

Answer (score 0):

OK, so not the easiest to read solution, but a bit shorter and cooler. ;-)

```
SELECT CURRENT-DATE - if((6+weekday(@dat))%7 > 4, (6+weekday(@dat))%7-3, 1) as  prev_workday
```

Explain: At least in my timezone gives weekday('monday-date') = 0, at Sunday 6. With `+6` I shift that to 6 .. 12. With modulu 7  (`%7`) I shift that to Saturday=4, Sunday=5, Monday=6.

So on all days which are after that shift bigger than 4 I reduce the day for this value - 3, otherwise I take the 'day before'. So on nsaturday I reduce for one day, on Sunday for two days and on Monday for three days.